# How to get % of two different cell with different position

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In column `E`, I want to show `E3` the % of `D3/B9` because:

1. it should find the `C3(CA)` from column `A(A9)`, and
2. then divide C3 value(D3) by A9 value(B9).

So,

- E3 will be 0.15(D3/B9)
- E4 will be 0.09(D4/B10)
- E5 will be 0.11(D5/B11)

Sample data:

```
1   A           B           C               D           E   Total      Rejected %
2               
3   TX              1       CA              34  
4   Austin          1       Los Angeles     1
5   CPE             3       Beverly Hills   7
6   CPE-E2E         3       Calabasas       2
7   WA              1       Culver City     14
8   Seattle         1       El Segundo      1
9   CA              221     Fremont         1
10  Los Angeles     11      FL              39
11  Beverly Hills   63      Tempa           1
12  Calabasas       10      Orlando         1
13  Culver City     58      Miami           5
14  El Segundo      5       Jacksonville    7
15  Fremont         7       Grand Total     73
16  FL              171
17  Tempa           2
18  Orlando         2
19  Miami           20
20  Tallahassee     10
21  Daytona Beach   8
22  Jacksonville    26
23  Grand Total     409
```

Comment: + 1 @aphoria: I had to cancel my post because of your comment :) I think you should post it as an answer ;)

Comment: I do not understand why this question was closed as off-topic.

Comment: @aphoria I'm guessing because some people don't consider excel formulas *programming* or *programming related*.

Comment: I think it's better to [post such question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123366/182741) on [SU](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: @j0k thanks for posting that link, I kind of thought that was the case and was considering searching or asking on meta about excel formulas. As it is I usually end up skipping those questions in the review queue even though I always felt that they probably fit better on [SU](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: Yes, there are are Excel questions that are not programming related. But, there are also Excel questions that ARE programming related...and I would argue that this one is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into `VLOOKUP`. It should help you.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx

### UPDATE

Two things...

1. I don't think you need `SUMPRODUCT()` here...it's not doing anything for you.
2. Put `=(D3)/(VLOOKUP(C3,$A$1:$D$100,2,FALSE)` in cell `E3`, then grab the square in the lower right-hand corner of cell `E3` and drag down to the last cell you want to calculate the percentage for. The formula in each cell will automatically update to reference the correct cells.

   Notice the `$` inside the `VLOOKUP`. Those tell the function to always use those cells and not autoupdate the reference.